# SQL Server column relationships

Tags: sql-server

I've got two tables.

One is "Corporations" (e.g., one record is for Taco Bell). The index and PK for this table is named "Id".

I've got another table: "Branches" (e.g., one record is for Los Angeles). The Branch table has a column named "Corporation". This column should only accept an "Id" value that corresponds with an "Id" in the "Corporations" table.

How do I enforce this? Do I add a constraint? How do I do that?

If I'm barking up the wrong tree, how do I define this relationship between Corporations and Branches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a FOREIGN KEY to Branches that references Corporations.

i.e.  in the CREATE TABLE for Branches:

```
CREATE TABLE Branches
(
  ...
  CorporationId int NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY FK_Branches_Corporations REFERENCES Corporations(Id)
  ...
)
```

Comment: or to modify your existing table:

ALTER TABLE Branches
ALTER CorporationId int NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY FK_Branches_Corporations REFERENCES Corporations(Id)